# env.local vs String var

Tags: typescript, firebase, next.js, environment-variables

I'm getting access denied error by firebase. I noticed that this error occurs when in the "configs.ts" file of the backend, when I pass the value of the "project_ID" by the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE, as in the code below:

```
import 'firebase/firestore'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
}

console.log("testing...", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID)

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp( firebaseConfig) : getApp()
const dataBase = getFirestore(app)
export { dataBase }
```

I also noticed that the code works if I assign the string value directly in the config file, without using environment variables, as in the code below:

```
import { getApp, initializeApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "APIKEYtesting_sdifoasdf5165sdf",
    authDomain: "next-URLTest_446546",
    projectId: "next-Test_454654",
  };
console.log("testing...", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID) // returns same value

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp( firebaseConfig) : getApp()
const dataBase = getFirestore(app)
export { dataBase }
```

The problem is that using the string directly in the configs would be a huge security hole. My question is why this happens, and how can I fix it.

Below the lines of code from my .env.local file:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY=exemple_APIKEY_a65sd4adf65s4df54-6as5d456,
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=next-exemple-4a4d5.url,
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=next-exemple-4a4d5,
```

Comment: The config will be visible to the client regardless... If you have proper security rules in place, it's not a security issue. That's how firebase was designed.

Comment: in this case I would not upload the file "env.local", which stores the values ​​related to firebase configs.

Comment: Assuming this is going to be a JS file that's served to the client, `process.env` variables aren't magically hidden from the user, they're used in build tools to replace the values in the final output. *The values will be visible to the client regardless, and this is by design.*

Comment: @Phix is right, values will be visible regardless. But it's not a bad thing to store them in .env file anyway. About the problem: have you tried to restart the app right? Also, are you variables contain some special symbols like `$` or `=` or something like that? You might want to wrap values into `"` for example. And escape other symbols.

Comment: ok, i understand about the visibility. But the problem is that using process.env results in "Access Denied", while assigning the "ID" string directly does not result in "Access Denied". Doing a console.log, I see that the process.env returns the same string value.

Comment: Maybe you mixed up project auth and project id in the env file? Otherwise if it shows in the log then it's working fine, just something wrong with your values

Comment: I don't think so, as I copied and pasted the firebase config line code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The problem is in the ".env.local" file, on the last line. I put a comma at the end of the last line that was being passed as if it were part of the variable's value.